# Get user geolocation automatically and put in hyperlink

Tags: php, google-maps

is there a way to get automatically, on page load, the user lat and long?

In my PHP script I want to populate automatically `$lat` and `$long`, but I do not know how:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=EN&region=EN&doflg=ptk&saddr='.$lat.','.$long.'&daddr=40.7033127,-73.979681&ie=UTF8&z=12" target="_blank">Get me there</a>
```

Any help is appreciated!

**SOLVED** (for people that will need an answer in the future!)

```
function GeoSuccess(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    $('#get-directions-link').append("<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=EN&region=EN&doflg=ptk&saddr="+latitude+","+longitude+"&daddr=<?php echo $place_locator->lat; ?>,<?php echo $place_locator->long; ?>&ie=UTF8&z=12' target='_blank'>Take me there</a>");
}
function error(msg) {
  error('There was an error pulling your location');
}
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GeoSuccess, error);
} else {
  error('Geolocation not supported');
}
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but do have some example? Because I am really stuck

Comment: [Examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+browser+user%27s+lat+and+long&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @Mark Google https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
  function geolocationSuccess(position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    // Place the marker
    youHere = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./images/Arrow.png");
    new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: userLatLng,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: youHere
    });
  }

  function geolocationError(positionError) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />";
  }

  function geolocateUser() {
    // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
      var positionOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
      };
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, positionOptions);
    }
    else
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API";
  }

  window.onload = geolocateUser;
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved yesterday in another way...updating the Question with the solution!